# Gimp Numix incompatibility?

Tags: gimp, numix

I know this will sound crazy, but my U15.10 and latest Gimp 2.8 crashes when I'm using the Numix theme/icons. Switching to something else makes Gimp work. Here's the tail of the errors:

```
 (gimp:19406): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x2A08EA0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-erase-mode"

(gimp:19406): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x2A09290 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:erase-mode"

(gimp:19406): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x2A096B0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:replace-mode"

(gimp:19406): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x2A09A80 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:anti-erase-mode"

(gimp:19406): Gimp-Widgets-CRITICAL **: gimp_device_info_set_device: assertion '(info->device == NULL && GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)) || (GDK_IS_DEVICE (info->device) && device == NULL)' failed
gimp: ../../../../src/cairo-scaled-font.c:459: _cairo_scaled_glyph_page_destroy: Assertion `!scaled_font->cache_frozen' failed.
gimp: terminated: Aborted
hercynian@hercynian-ThinkPad-T430:~$ 
(script-fu:19413): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error
```

I've done a total purge, reinstall, to no avail. I know none of the errors looks like it has anything to do with Numix, but, again, when I go to another theme/icons, Gimp works.

Comment: File a bug on Numix's github page or Launchpad?

Comment: It seems that this has to do with the font, same issue filed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cairo/+bug/1476736)

Comment: @bistoco Thanks, that was indeed the fix, i.e., I was using the Terminus font. Canning it solved the problem. Now, what the devil is wrong with Terminus?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is using Numix theme, Terminus Font and Gimp together, 
as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cairo/+bug/1476736).

Changing the font fix the problem (as you tested already).